# python- https/json parser error issue

Tags: python, json

I am trying to parse json data from a site that shows values of crypto currency. I am trying to parse it using python. I am a little lost on how to show the output.

API: `https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=XMR&tsyms=USD`

```
# code starts below

import requests

# Set the request parameters
url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=XMR&tsyms=USD'

# Fetch url
print("Fetching url..")

# Do the HTTP get request
response = requests.get(url, verify=True) #Verify is check SSL certificate

# Error handling

# Check for HTTP codes other than 200
if response.status_code != 200:
    print('Status:', response.status_code, 'Problem with the request. Exiting.')
exit()

# Decode the JSON response into a dictionary and use the data

USD = response.json()

output = USD[0]['USD']

print('Output USD:'), USD

# code ends
```

I am getting a response code 200 because IDLE tries to exit. The code is based off another project and I don't believe I am parsing json correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if response.status_code != 200:
    print('Status:', response.status_code, 'Problem with the request. Exiting.')
exit()
```

The way you've indented, Python will always call exit(). You want it to call exit() only if there was actually an error, like so:

```
if response.status_code != 200:
    print('Status:', response.status_code, 'Problem with the request. Exiting.')
    exit()
```

However, you have another problem. You're trying to assign "output" the value of an object in USD; USD doesn't exist:

```
data = response.json()

output = USD[0]['USD'] #"USD" doesn't exist. It's the value you're trying to find, not the json that contains the object itself.

print('Output USD:'), USD #"USD" doesn't exist. I think you meant to print "output" here, which is the value you're setting in the line above.
```

Instead, try this:

```
data = response.json()

output = data["USD"]

print('Output USD:'), output
```

Comment: Thank you. No error now. However no output. Output is blank. "Fetching url..
Output USD: "

Comment: Using parts of the answer below I now have what works. output = data['USD'] print('Output USD:', data)

Answer (score 1):

Your `exit()` line is not indented correctly. Try this:

```
if response.status_code != 200:
    print('Status:', response.status_code, 'Problem with the request. Exiting.')
    exit()
```

Additionally, even though you are parsing the JSON correctly, you incorrectly use the resulting data. Try this:

```
output = USD['USD']         # Note: "[0]" not required
print('Output USD:', USD)   # Note: ", USD" inside the parentheses
```